# Retaining selection when calling javaScript function from android application

Tags: android, android-webview

I have embedded a WebView in my android application and used

> webview.loadUrl("javascript:myFunction()")

to call the javaScript functions on the loaded url, but the problem I face is, if i had any selection on the webview, it is cleared when webview.loadUrl() call is invoked.

Is there any way to retain the **selection** as the javascript functions are called from android application?